# What does "worse" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What could be meant by **worse** in sentence "the smell of sweat and worse"? Can it be **puke**?

Here is some context:

> Her eyes shimmered with tears of self-pity. For years, she thought,
>   she’d honestly believed nothing could be as bad as prison—the sound of
>   cell doors locking shut, **the smell of sweat and worse**, the menial
>   work, the disgusting food.
>  
>   Excerpt from *Hideaway* by Nora Roberts

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not **explicitly** stated in the excerpt on purpose. **Worse** doesn't have a special meaning in that context. You have to use your **imagination**, in English or in your own native language. The author is talking about a prison. For example: What about the smell of urine and feces from non-working johns? It's worse than the smell of sweat.

@KateBunting has pointed that ***worse*** in this kind of context has the meaning of 'other things which I don't wish to specify but which you can **imagine** for yourself'. The author does not want to explicitly point what I have wondered above. Notice that Kate and I have mentioned **imagination** on your part as reader.

Comment: Oh, yes, I thought about "worse" as a noun. So it's like "smell of sweat and worse things?"

Comment: @KristinaLukosevice Yes, it is.

Comment: I would say that _worse_ in this kind of context has the meaning of 'other things which I don't wish to specify but which you can imagine for yourself'.

Comment: @KateBunting You're right. Maybe I haven't taken that into account, that the author doesn't want to be so explicit.